# how to use my version of zend framework included with project instead of installed version on server

Tags: zend-framework, version

how to make the project use the zend framework included in the library folder instead of using the installed version on the server . because sometimes the version on server is lower than the one used in the development!! is there a way to force it to use library in library directory??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put in before the server's path in `include_path`.

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/my/path/to/zf',
    get_include_path(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tomáš Fejfar 's solution is of course the standard on the fly solution. You also have a few other options though.

- you can remove the "installed" version on the server (if nothing else uses it)
- you can create subdirectories in the server library and use per project paths
- you can skip the usage of the include path entirely and work with Symlinks, we prefer that